# How to select values in a multiselector based on the selected values of another multiselector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two multiselectors as follows, the first one using the Chosen plugin:

```
<%= select_tag :provinces, options_for_select(DataHelper::all_provinces_captions.zip(DataHelper::all_provinces_ids)), {:multiple => true, class: 'chosen-select chzn-select', :data => {:placeholder => 'Filter Provinces/States'}, :style => "width: 100%; height: 100px;"}%>

<%= f.select :province_ids,
  (DataHelper::all_provinces_captions.zip(DataHelper::all_provinces_ids)),
  { include_blank: true },
  {multiple: true, data: {placeholder: 'Filter Provinces/States'} }
%>
```

I want to make the selected values in the `:provinces` selector, the same as the selected value of the `:province_ids` selector, on page load. Something similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#education_plan_province_ids option:selected").each(function () {
    $("#provinces option[value='"this"']").prop('selected', true); 
  });
});
```

Except, of course, that doesn't work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var updateDropdown = function() {
  $("#provinces option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
  var educationPlanProvinceIds = $("#education_plan_province_ids").val()
  if (educationPlanProvinceIds) {
    educationPlanProvinceIds.forEach(function(id) {
      $('#provinces option[value="' + id + '"]').prop("selected", true)
    })
  }
  // chosen needs to know when its underlying select element has been changed
  $("#provinces").trigger("chosen:updated")
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateDropdown()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="education_plan_province_ids" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="true">3</option>
</select>
<select id="provinces" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on page load, instead of on select change?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't expect either of the selects to change, you can just run the function inside the change listener on load instead.

Comment: Can you change your answer accordingly? If you are wrapping it with (document).ready, then the function inside doesn't work anymore (no more `this` for example).

Comment: Ah, cool! I added a console.log and the console is getting the right value, it is just not finding the values and setting them to selected, ie.         `$('#provinces option[value="' + value + '"]').prop('selected', true)` is not working, and I think it's cause we are using the Chosen plugin.

Comment: So it's getting the correct values from the first dropdown (which IS a chosen) but isn't setting them properly on the second select (which ISN'T a chosen)?

Comment: #provinces IS a Chosen, and #education_plan_provinces_ids ISNT a Chosen (what you said, *reversed*)

Comment: try adding `$("#provinces").trigger("chosen:updated")` at the end of the function.  I'll edit it also

Comment: That works! Can you change the #select1 to education_plan_province_ids and the #select2 to #provinces, and I will accept?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#education_plan_province_ids option:selected").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#provinces option[value='"+val+"']").attr('selected','selected');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="education_plan_province_ids" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" >Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" selected>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>


<select id="provinces" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is close ~~ but it doesn't work, I think because we are using the Chosen library (I edited the question).

Comment: It is getting the values, just not assigning them the selected value

Comment: Same issue, I'm afraid :(